# Py2App: File Needs to Be Included, but it is Too Large

Tags: python, compression, py2app

At the moment, I'm using py2app to convert python scripts to a standalone application. However, my scripts require a 2GB unix executable. Py2App isn't able to process a file that large as an included file or resource, as it produces an error in the creation of the standalone file. Is there anyway I can include this file in my standalone app?

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: The only 2gb executables I know about contain archives themselves. Could you extract or partially extract the executable before packaging it?

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience with Pyinstaller, but do you have to put the executable through Py2App? Might it be possible to package it with your executable in the same directory so it will be found and run? Is producing a single file very important, or could you include it in a directory with other dependencies?